# Stop And Unbind Service From diffrent Activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-preferences

I am giving exit option in my preference activity. In that option i want to unbind and stop service. But My application get closed but service do not stop. I am starting and binding service from another activity. In preference activity i am not starting or binding.

Here is my code of preference activity :

```
Preference exit = findPreference("Exit");
        exit.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Exit :")
                .setMessage("Are You Sure??")
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));                              
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                .show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But myservice does not stop. how do i stop my service ?? pleaze help me..

Edit :

Got error

```
01-24 10:20:30.699: E/AndroidRuntime(18503): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 10:20:30.699: E/AndroidRuntime(18503): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.androidhive.musicplayer.SettingsActivity$1@405c7af8
01-24 10:20:30.699: E/AndroidRuntime(18503):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:891)
01-24 10:20:30.699: E/AndroidRuntime(18503):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:901)
01-24 10:20:30.699: E/AndroidRuntime(18503):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:352)
```

Code that i have changed :

```
getApplicationContext().stopService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MyService.class));                    getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally services are stopped in `onPause` or `onDestroy` of your *last* activity.

I use this code in one of my projects:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getApplicationContext().unbindService(service);
}
```

This code exits my service on exiting my app.

Comment: my Ondestroy() Method is not called.. What have you written to exit app??

Comment: Nothing special it is the normal livecycle of an activity. It takes some time until Android kills a background app. If you handle rotation events you could also use onPause.

Comment: See also the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Comment: my application exited. my player does not stop which i have started using service. In service class i have written onDestroy() method, which is stopping my player (mp.stop()). Do you have ne idea to call onDestroy() method of service.??

Comment: Oh no you need to implement the onDestroy/onPause in your activity

Comment: yes, i have done the same. in activity i have override onDestroy(). But my player does not stop which i have started through service for implementing playback service.